# Error using readObject of kryo in scala?

Tags: scala, serialization, deserialization

I am using Kyro package for serializing and de-serializing object in Scala. Deserializing scala object from saved file through following error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor)
```

The scala object serialized:

```
class serialzObj(val token: Token){
         def this() = this(null)
....
}
```

The code used for de-serialization:

```
var kryo = new Kryo(); 
var input = new Input(new FileInputStream(fName));
var index = kryo.readObject(input, classOf[serialzObj]);
input.close();
```

UPDATE: The issue was fixed. The default constructor was missing in the TOKEN object.

Comment: If you want to use Kryo with Scala you should take a look at Chill from Twitter (https://github.com/twitter/chill).  If you use Chill and convert your class to a case class things should work for you.

Comment: Well, since it has a no-arg constructor, are you sure that 1) you recompiled the class after adding one; 2) that you don't have an old version of your class somewhere on the classPath?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have fixed the issue. The issue was the object Token dint have a default constructor.